# Using an overlay on lstinputlistings in latex

Tags: beamer, listings

I want to have to multiple overlayed lstinputlistings on one slide in a presentation, created with latex and documentclass beamer. The only solutions I find are for lstlistings, but those don't work for lstinputlistings. My Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Packages required for correct language representation and input
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Packages needed for the diagrams
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[ngerman]{struktex}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Packages used for the code
\usepackage{listings}

% Defining the theme for the presentation
\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\useoutertheme{default}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

% Defining how lstlistings should look like
\lstset{rangeprefix=\#\{\ ,% curly left brace plus space
    rangesuffix=\ \},
    frame = single,
    breaklines=true
    breakautoindent=true,
    postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}}}

% Replacing the navigation bar by the slidenumbers
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

begin{document}
...blablabla...
\begin{frame}{Python-Skript -- Lesen der Daten 1}
    \only<1->{\lstinputlisting[linerange=imp-end, includerangemarker=false,
    language=Python]{../daten/einnahmen_plot.py}}
    \only<2->{\lstinputlisting[linerange=reading1-end, includerangemarker=false,
    language=Python]{../daten/einnahmen_plot.py}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This so far works fine. But if I replace the "\only" directive by "\uncover", I get lots of errors (too many to show them here). I also tried packing the lstinputlistings into semiverbatims, like you can do it with lstlistings, it doesn't work. Same with blocks etc.
Any ideas how I could solve this? I DON'T want to use only, I need an actual overlay like uncover or something here!

Comment: Can you please make your example compilable? We do not have `../daten/einnahmen_plot.py`

Comment: It doesn't matter for the question. But I found a simple solution. Thanks nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple solution. Problem was that I set beamercovered to transparent. It seems LaTeX doesn't like that for listings/blocks. Just remove

```
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
```

or set it to invisible before the listings.

```
...
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
% frame with blocks and listings etc.
...
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
...
```

This makes overlayed listings/blocks with listings possible, and sets beamercovered back to transparent after.